# Overwriting Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So in my bootstrap.css I have:

```
    .form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 34px;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.428571429;
      color: #555555;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
      -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
              transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;

}
```

And in my own .css file that I loaded after bootstrap.css:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 1.928571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: left;
  background-color: #002b36;
  border: 0px none #002b36;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: none 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

Everything is overwritten except for the

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: none 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: none 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
```

I can tell since if I change that snippet in bootstrap.css to match what I have in my own css file that it actually changes on the webpage. So for some reason, my own css overwrites everything except for those two lines about box-shadows, and I don't know why.

Comment: That's because your CSS line `-webkit-box-shadow: none ...` is not valid CSS. It is never applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try shorten it to valid CSS like:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```